# Create hyperlink for accessing Multiple excel sheets by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple txt files which I am able to merge and write into different excel sheets by the below code:

```
for file in list(file_lists):
    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
    df = pd.read_table(filename,sep="|",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=file[:-4], index=False,header=True)
writer.save()
```

I want to now create another sheet (Name = "Homepage") which will contain different sheet names as hyperlinks. I should be able to click on that hyperlink which will take me to  the respective sheets. Is there any way I can do that? Any sample codes would be helpful, the similar codes available in SO are not helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a `pandas` question, as the `pandas.to_excel` function has very little to do with the formatting and markup used in the excel sheet.

You can look at `xlsxwriter` which specifically formats `xlsx` files.

This is a sample code for formatting `hyperlinks`, it is adapted from the [documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hyperlink.html) where you can read more.

```
###############################################################################
#
# Example of how to use the XlsxWriter module to write hyperlinks
#
# Copyright 2013-2018, John McNamara, jmcnamara@cpan.org
#
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hyperlink.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Hyperlinks')

# Format the first column
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Add a sample alternative link format.
red_format = workbook.add_format({
    'font_color': 'red',
    'bold':       1,
    'underline':  1,
    'font_size':  12,
})

# Write some hyperlinks
worksheet.write_url('A1', 'http://www.python.org/')  # Implicit format.
worksheet.write_url('A3', 'http://www.python.org/', string='Python Home')
worksheet.write_url('A5', 'http://www.python.org/', tip='Click here')
worksheet.write_url('A7', 'http://www.python.org/', red_format)
worksheet.write_url('A9', 'mailto:jmcnamara@cpan.org', string='Mail me')

# Write a URL that isn't a hyperlink
worksheet.write_string('A11', 'http://www.python.org/')

workbook.close()
```